# Is it possible to create an instance of a particular location on the screen (using auto layout)?

Tags: swift, animation

I have 4 playing cards on the screen. At the press of a button, I want one of the cards at random to move to the middle of the top half of the screen. Is it possible to create an instance of a constraint (eg: centerXAnchor with constant 0, and centerYAnchor with constant -200) so that I can use CGAffineTransform and move the random image to this point?

Ive tried creating an instance of a CGRect Frame:

```
let destination = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
```

but this does not move evenly across devices.

Answer (score 1):

> An affine transformation matrix is used to rotate, scale, translate, or skew the objects you draw in a graphics context.

I don't think CGAffineTransform is the ideal thing to use for this task. You aren't doing any the above things (rotate, scale, translate, or skew).

I think you would likely be best using `UIView.animateWithDuration`

```
let cardSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
let card = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: cardSize))

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
    card.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), size: cardSize)
}
```